# Keyword Collection, ManyToOne or OneToMany relationship?

Tags: database-design, hibernate, relationships

I hope this is the right place for this type of problem.

An Object of my class `Movie` can have several `keywords` ( like 'fight club', 'brad', 'fincher'),  and be part of different `categories` (like 'Drama', 'Best Movies Ever') I implemented them as ManyToMany:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Keyword.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Keyword> keywords;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = MovieCategory.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<MovieCategory> movieCategories;
```

Somehow I don' think, this is not the correct relationshipmodel, how would you implement this? Right now hibernate wont allow me to fetch.eager. fetch.lazy is okay. I found this link http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/ but it didn't answered my question.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about Hibernate so can't help with your fetching, but many-to-many is absolutely how these things are related. Every movie can have multiple keywords and categories, and every keyword and category can apply to multiple movies.

Comment: See ManyToMany bidirectional eager fetching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978733/hibernate-manytomany-bidirectional-eager-fetching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use @ManyToMany? 
If different movies have different keywords and a keyword can be related to different movies then that requires @ManyToMany. The same goes for categories.